# mkdir() function: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I have the code:

```
$path_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/facebook/user/".$userid."/coverphoto/";
if(!file_exists($path_directory) && !is_dir($path_directory)){
    mkdir($path_directory, true);
```

and it is telling me Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory

and I do not know what to do.

Help is very much appreciated

Comment: Have you read mkdir’a documentation? The second parameter is the mode (eg. 0777). The third parameter is a Boolean.

Comment: If I have (0777) then it gives me permission denied I also read that sometimes you don't need 0777

Comment: 0777 is default mode and most open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mkdir() like this

```
mkdir($path_directory, 0777, true);
```

FYI: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

And you may use below code to make sure you have enough permission first.

```
$path_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/facebook";
mkdir($path_directory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. First check if the user has his own directory

   $user_path_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/facebook/user/".$userid;

   if(!file_exists($user_path_directory) && !is_dir($user_path_directory)) {
       mkdir($path_directory, true);
   }
2. If the user has his own directory, lets create his coverphoto directory.

   $path_directory = $user_path_directory."/coverphoto/"

   if(!file_exists($path_directory) && !is_dir($path_directory)) {
       mkdir($path_directory, true);
   }

Comment: There's no need for the first step, since the recursive parameter from `mkdir` takes care of that

Comment: No, but I was just assuming he doesn't also have a file with the same name as the `$userid`

Comment: it gives me two of the same errors

mkdir() function: No such file or directory